# What would be the best practice for displaying a web page with 50 sub menus without scroll?

Tags: website-design, menu, scrolling

I would like to know how we can best represent a webpage with 50 sub menus or more without scrolling the page. Currently, I have implemented a side menu which pops out on click of the hamburger icon. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Best practice: don't have 50 submenus.  Sounds like you ought to restructure the site.

Comment: Why don't you want to scroll the page? It may be that scrolling turns out to be a perfectly good option. Don't close off potential solutions up front.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is group your categories by major themes and use a similar style as bestbuy.com where categories appears in a dropdown and when you go above one category, the window expands and shows other relevant categories based on that theme.

[image: bestbuy dropdown layout]

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @dan1111, one alternative, I can think of is a Chris Coyer's implementation for big drop down.

You can see the example below:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/

But honestly that would be an unfamiliar behavior for the user and that cannot happen inside a side menu.

The other thing is sidr.js which you could see been used here,
http://www.uscourts.gov/
If you click you can have the drop down load  horizontally